# how to get java fx thread access

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use d3.js visuals in my java desktop application by integrating javafx-d3 library. I am using the code like this

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
   @Override
        public void run()
        {
            runDemoSuite(demoMenuBox, demoPreferenceBox);
        }
};

Platform.runLater(runnable);
browser = new JavaFxD3Browser(runnable, true);
```

The issue is that the "runnable" is not "JavaFX Application Thread". When I run it with "Platform" then it becomes "JavaFX Application Thread", other its a regular thread. How can  I get the access to this thread and pass it to JavaFxD3Browser function.

Answer (score 1):

> "runnable" is not "JavaFX Application Thread"

`Runnable` is an interface that allows abstraction of some piece of code. It cannot be "a thread".

It is not clear whether you want to use `Runnable` or `Thread`, so in case you want to wrap an arbitrary piece of code then use:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        // code here will run on the JavaFX Application Thread
    };
};
```

The `runnable` object regardless of its caller thread will execute its wrapped code on the JavaFX Application Thread.

> How can I get the access to this thread

You can obtain the `Thread` object that has name "JavaFX Application Thread" as follows:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    private Thread fxThread;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // fxThread is the JavaFX Application Thread after this call
            fxThread = Thread.currentThread();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to access the FxThread outside of the function, its null.